# jQuery ajax return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

How can I return the value "**pinNumber**" from jquery ajax so I can append it outside of the ajax. Here is my code

```
var x = pinLast + 1;
    for(i=x;i<=pinMany;i++) {
        var i = x++;
        var cardNumber = i.toPrecision(8).split('.').reverse().join('');
        var pinNumber = '';

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: "request_type=generator",
            async: false,
            success: function(msg){
                var pinNumber = msg;
                return pinNumber;
                //pin number should return
            }
        });

        jQuery('.pin_generated_table').append(cardNumber+' = '+pinNumber+'
');
        // the variable pinNumber should be able to go here

    }
```

Please ask me if you don't understand.. ^^ thanks

Comment: Yet another "how do I return data from an asynchronous function" question. This kind of question is asked all too often. Voting to close.

Comment: How dare you ask this question! I vote to remove this person from the earth.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous by default, you cannot return a value from the callback without making a synchronous call, which you almost certainly don't want to do.

You should supply a real callback function to the `success:` handler, and put your program logic there.

Comment: oh thanks so much.. i already got the idea.. :) by putting my varibles inside of the ajax then append it in the inside.

Comment: I don't really see the need for callbacks in SYNC AJAX.

Comment: Sync Ajax is an oxymoron. And sync XHR sucks.

Answer (score 5):

```
var pinNumber = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data.php",
    data: "request_type=generator",
    async: false
}).responseText;
jQuery('.pin_generated_table').append(cardNumber+' = '+pinNumber+' ');
```

Comment: Pls dont use this whoever will read this!!! This is WRONG! Our programmer now thinks that ajax is working like this!

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with [variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope). The local variable `pinNumber` you create is not accessible outside its wrapping function.

Perhaps declare `pinNumber` globally or if it'll do the trick, simply stick your `.append()` inside your success function.

Comment: It has nothing to do with variable scope; the `.append` is executing before the success callback.

Comment: `async` is false though, meaning `.append` will run after the AJAX call.

Comment: OP doesn't need to declare the `pinNumber` globally, it will suffice to not use the `var` keyword in the assignment to it inside the success handler. The assignment will then affect the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 3):

```
var _successEvent = function(response){
    $('.pin_generated_table').append(cardNumber + ' = ' + response);
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data.php",
    data: "request_type=generator"
}).done(_successEvent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example:

`window.variable = 'some data';`

This make you variable global and you can access to this from anywhere

Comment: But when would the implementer know when the value set for `window.variable` is changed and accessible with the new value?

Answer (score -3):

Here is the simple solution.

```
    //---------------------------Ajax class ------------------------------//
    function AjaxUtil()
    {
            this.postAjax = function(Data,url,callback)
            {
              $.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 async: true,     //must be syncronous request! or not return ajax results
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: Data,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(json)
                 {
                     callback(json);
                 }
               });
            }//--end postAjax
    }
    //--------------------------------End class--------------------//
    var ajaxutil = new AjaxUtil();

    function callback(response)
    {
          alert(response); //response data from ajax call
    }

  var data={};
  data.yourdata = 'anydata';
  var url = 'data.php';

  ajaxutil.postAJax(data,url,callback);
```

Comment: Your comment on `async: true` is simply lying and wrapping the callback in another function is pointless. Besides, this is  unnecessary. What does wrapping it into a class have to do with the question?

Comment: Regardless of any of that he's the only one that gave a proper example of the use of `success:`. The accepted "answer" isn't even an answer as it doesn't give an example.