# How to return value from $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, return, getjson

I'm having a problem with method using $.getJSON. It's very simple and it looks like that:

```
function lastID(query) {

  $.getJSON(url+query ,function(json){

    var type_id = json.data;

});

    return type_id // doesn't work
}
```

Could you please tell me how to return type_id to some other value for instance like this:

```
var returnedID = lastID(query); // this schould me equal to returned type_id from lastID method.
```

Many thanks for your reply

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632039/return-value-from-ajax-call)

Comment: This question comes up far too often, anyway see: [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 6):

You will need to do something like the following, since you cannot return a value from an asynchronous request. This question has been asked many times. [jquery - return value using ajax result on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302702/jquery-return-value-using-ajax-result-on-success) and [jQuery ajax return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982983/jquery-ajax-return-value)

```
function processType(id){
    ....
}

function lastID(query){
    $.getJSON(url+query ,function(json){
        processType(json.data);
    });
}
```