# How can I return value from $.getJSON function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return value from $.getJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911867/how-to-return-value-from-getjson)

```
        function get_url(){
            var returnValue  = null;
            $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:1337/?callback=?&command=get_url', "", function(data){
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                returnValue = data[0].get_url;
                console.log(returnValue); // "not_null"

            }); 
            console.log(returnValue);  // "null"
            return returnValue;
        }
```

Why function don't return "not_null" ?

Answer (score 3):

The call to `$.getJSON` is asynchronous and won't have completed before your `get_url` function has returned. There won't be a value in `returnValue` to return.

You need to either make the call synchronous by using `$.ajax` with `async:false` rather than `$.getJSON` or handle the return value in an asynchronous manner, modifying the calling logic to not expect it straight away.

```
$.getJSON
```

is simply shorthand for a call to $.ajax, so you can do this instead:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  async: false,
  success: callback
});
```

Comment: Turn your call to $.getJSON into a call to $.ajax with async:false. The code in your success function will then work.

Comment: Don't work.

function get_url(){
 var returnValue  = null;
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:1337/?callback=?&command=get_url',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function(data){
   data = $.parseJSON(data);
   console.log(data[0].get_url);
   returnValue = data[0].get_url;
   }
 });
 console.log(returnValue);
 return returnValue;
}